# Possible ways of making an Object immutable

Tags: java, immutability

I am looking for some efficient way for building a immutable class, just like Java's String class.

Comment: Are you looking for a class that's like String functionality-wise? I didn't read your question that way at first, but if you do I'll change my answer with some String-specific examples.

Comment: String is a special citizen in Java. It isn't exactly a primitive type, but you also can't consider it a class. String is the only "class" that overloads the + operator. Adding two Strings will get new a new one. Operator overloading isn't allowed with regular classes.

Comment: Can't consider String a class???

Comment: Does the String class override the + operator? Or does the compiler do the magic for you?

Comment: Yes, not functionality wise. Its behavior should be be same as what an immutable class should do and should not do.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: I meant that you can't compare classes you write with String class. String class is special.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. All the fields must be
   `private` and preferably `final`
2. Ensure the class cannot be
   overridden - make the class final,
   or use static factories and keep
   constructors private
3. Fields must be populated from the
   Constructor/Factory
4. Don't provide any setters for the
   fields
5. Watch out for collections. Use
   `Collections.unmodifiable*`. Also, collections should contain only immutable Objects
6. All the getters must provide
   immutable objects or use [defensive copying](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15)
7. Don't provide any methods that
   change the internal state of the
   Object.

[Tom Hawtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) pointed out that `final` can be optional. `String` `class` has a cache `hash` var that is only assigned when the hash function is called.

Comment: There's an instance field in the Sun String implementation which is not final.

Comment: Nice point. 'final' is not a requirement. The hash var in String is the perfect example.

Comment: You should also think about making make the class final to ensure that no derived class exposes a protected field.

Comment: @DR, I agree. Immutable classes should be final.

Comment: hashCode is not final because it is set lazily.  It will have only one real value however so it will appear final.

Comment: I use immutable classes which extend other immutable classes all the time.  Not sure why you need to make an immutable class final unless you are concerned that it might be extended with a mutable one. Otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 1):

An object is immutable if none of its fields can be modified, so those fields must be `final`. If you don't want your object to be subclassed, you can make the class itself `final` as well, just like String is.
To easily construct an immutable object with a lot of information, you should look at the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)

For more information, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Comment: And if he wants no subclasses, he should also make the class itself final.

Answer (score 1):

If you populate all fields using the constructor and make the fields final - you are partway there.

If the fields use custom types - you may need to make them immutable as well.

Any fields that are collections should use the unmodifiable collections - to be on the safe side.

You need to worry about the object graph!

Any methods on the object need to take care with non-final fields. E.g. String.add creates a **new** String. If you need to mutate one field - do so via a copy constructor.

Finally make the object final.

Comment: Would really appreciate if you can explain this with the help of an example.

Comment: If you haven't already got a copy - get a copy of Effective Java by Josh Bloch. He explains this far better than I ever can!

Comment: Surely, will do it today itself. Thanks